# SVGP for US Flight data

Tags: gpflow

My problem is the optimization issue for SVIGP in the US Flight dataset.
I implemented the SVGP model for the US flight data mentioned in the Hensman 2014 using the number of inducing point = 100, batch_size = 1000, learning rate = 1e-5 and maxiter = 500.

The result is pretty strange end ELBO does not increase and it have large variance no matter how I tune the learning rate

## Initialization

```py
M = 100
D = 8
def init():
    kern = gpflow.kernels.RBF(D, 1, ARD=True)
    Z = X_train[:M, :].copy()
    m = gpflow.models.SVGP(X_train, Y_train.reshape([-1,1]), kern, gpflow.likelihoods.Gaussian(), Z, minibatch_size=1000)
    return m
m = init()
```

## Inference

```py
m.feature.trainable = True
opt = gpflow.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.00001)
m.compile()
opt.minimize(m, step_callback=logger, maxiter = 500)
plt.plot(logf)
plt.xlabel('iteration')
plt.ylabel('ELBO')
```

## Result：

[image: result]

## Added Results

Once I add more iterations and use large learning rate. It is good to see that ELBO increases as iterations increase. But it is very confused that both RMSE(root mean square error) for training and testing data increase too. Do you have some suggestions?
Figures and codes shown as follows:

ELBOs vs iterations

[image: ELBOs vs iterations]

Train RMSEs vs iterations

[image: Train RMSEs vs iterations]

Test RMSEs vs iterations

[image: Test RMSEs vs iterations]

Using logger

```py
def logger(x):
    print(m.compute_log_likelihood())
    logx.append(x)
    logf.append(m.compute_log_likelihood())
    logt.append(time.time() - st)
    py_train = m.predict_y(X_train)[0]
    py_test = m.predict_y(X_test)[0]
    rmse_hist.append(np.sqrt(np.mean((Y_train - py_train)**2)))
    rmse_test_hist.append(np.sqrt(np.mean((Y_test - py_test)**2)))
    logger.i+=1
logger.i = 1
```

And the full code is shown through [link](https://github.com/Corleno/RGPLVM/blob/master/MEBLO/src/Comparison_flight.ipynb).

Comment: 500 iterations is far too few. I don't know how many it needs to complete off the top of my head, but try running it for 50000 iterations with a learning rate of 1e-3.

Comment: I changed the tuning parameters, but the changings of RMSEs of both training and testing data are very strange. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Have you looked at what your hyperparameters go to? I suspect the prior variance of the GP may be going to zero. This is a local optimum. The usual way to deal with this, is to fix the kernel hyperparameters for some initial iterations. Hensman 2013 does this. A good way to identify when this happens is to compare the elbo to that of a noise model.

Comment: I find out that my issue is that the optimization is difficult to learn the ARD length-scale parameters. After I do a normalization on the raw data for each input dimension. The algorithm works. Thanks for your suggestions!